# Gekko Auto Trading bot install failure on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, gekko

I am a super noob at coding in ubuntu and am trying to setup the gekko auto trading bot on a web server i created. I was using some instructions on a website i found and have finished everything when i try to start the serivce with : node gekko --ui i keep getting the following erro:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:944
throw err;
^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'relieve'
Require stack:
- /root/gekko/core/workers/dateRangeScan/parent.js
- /root/gekko/web/routes/scanDateRange.js
- /root/gekko/web/server.js
- /root/gekko/gekko.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:                                                                                15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/gekko/core/workers/dateRangeScan/parent.js:1:                                                                                16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10                                                                                )
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/root/gekko/core/workers/dateRangeScan/parent.js',
    '/root/gekko/web/routes/scanDateRange.js',
    '/root/gekko/web/server.js',
    '/root/gekko/gekko.js'
  ]
}
root@hwsrv-873622:~/gekko#
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Gekko Bitcoin Open Source Auto-Trading Bot](https://gekko.wizb.it/) is different than the [Gekko Optimization Suite](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that is [tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gekko) in this post.

> GEKKO is a Python package for machine learning and optimization of
> mixed-integer and differential algebraic equations. It is coupled with
> large-scale solvers for linear, quadratic, nonlinear, and mixed
> integer programming (LP, QP, NLP, MILP, MINLP). Modes of operation
> include parameter regression, data reconciliation, real-time
> optimization, dynamic simulation, and nonlinear predictive control.
> GEKKO is an object-oriented Python library to facilitate local
> execution of APMonitor.

Installation of the Gekko Optimization Suite is with:

```sh
python -m pip install gekko
```

Both packages are released under the MIT License with [Gekko Optimization Suite source code](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO) available on GitHub. The Bitcoin trading bot is no longer maintained but the [source code](https://github.com/askmike/gekko/tree/c13c3ab64ba24b688dd02ebd259e60457ce1eb28) is available.